# Reverse function on binary gives unexpected result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, binary, reverse

I try binary to integer for migration in sqlserver

```
declare @little binary(4) set @little = 0x95916c00
select @little as [Litttle], convert(binary(4), reverse(@little)) as Big
```

expected: 0x006c9195
actual: 0x006c9591

I guess utf-encoding recognize '0x9591' is one word...
How does it fix?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might get you the result (in a varchar variable).

```
declare @little binary(4) 
set @little = 0x95916c00
declare @string varchar(100)
declare @reversed_string varchar(100)

select @string = master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@little)

select @reversed_string = substring(@string, 1, 2) + reverse(substring (@string, 3, len(@string)))

select @reversed_string
```

Answer (score 0):

> why you want to revesrse only last char ?

in case someone looking to convert whole binary to varchar as it is 
then try this,

```
declare @little binary(4) set @little = 0x95916c00

select reverse(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr (@little))
```